# Testing linked server conccetion inside trigger or procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, linked-server

I wrote a trigger that updates local table and similar table on linked server.

`CREATE TRIGGER myTtableUpdate ON myTable

AFTER UPDATE
AS

IF (COLUMNS_UPDATED() > 0)

BEGIN

  DECLARE @retval int;

  BEGIN TRY

    EXEC @retval = sys.sp_testlinkedserver N'my_linked_server';

  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

    SET @retval = sign(@@error);

  END CATCH;`

IF (@retval = 0)
  BEGIN
    UPDATE remoteTable SET remoteTable.datafield = i.datafield
      FROM my_linked_server.remote_database.dbo.myTable remoteTable
      INNER JOIN inserted i ON (remoteTable.id = i.id)
  END
END  -- end of trigger

Unfortunately when connection is down I get error message
*'Msg 3616, Level 16, State 1, Line 2'*
*'Transaction doomed in trigger. Batch has been aborted'*
and locally made update is rolled back.

Is there a way to maintain this error and keep local updates?
Note that I'm using SQL Server 2005 Express Edition on both PCs running Windows XP Pro.

edit1: SQL server is Express Edition
edit2: Both PCs run Windows XP Pro so these aren't servers

Comment: see my latest comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't write to the remote server in the trigger.

- create a local table to store rows that need to be pushed to the remote server
- insert into this new local table in the trigger
- create a job that runs every N minutes to insert from this local table into remote server.

this job can run a procedure that can test for the connection, and when it is back up, it will handle all rows in the new local table.  It can process the rows in the local table this way:

```
declare @OutputTable table (RowID int not null)

insert into my_linked_server.remote_database.dbo.myTable remoteTable(...columns...)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.RowID
    INTO @OutputTable
    SELECT ...columns...
        from NewLocalTable

delete NewLocalTable
   from NewLocalTable           n
       inner join @OutputTable  o ON n.RowID=o.RowID
```

**EDIT based OP comment**
after inserting into this new local table start the job from the trigger (sp_start_job), it will run in its own scope.  If you can't use sql server jobs, use xp_cmdshell to execute the stored procedure  (lookup SQLCMD or ISQL or OSQL, I'm not sure what you have).  still schedule the job every N minutes, so it will eventually run when the connection comes up.

Comment: This could almost work except the delay of scheduled job. Plus on Express Edition I'd have to use Windows scheduler which makes the delay reeeeeally long.

Comment: With the scheduler you can run stuff every X minutes - if that is not good enough you will have to revisit your design and architecture.

Comment: Since the expected outcome was that the update would be populated right away or ,in case network error, never then I'd probably have to run the scheduler in every minute which doesn't seem like very appealing solution.

Comment: schedule if for every 15 minutes, but run it on demand from the trigger.  if the version from the trigger fails, it will take at worst case 15 minutes to be tried again.  If another insert comes along it would be tried sooner.  you just need to run the on demand version using sp_start_job or xp_cmdshell, so if it fails, you don't roll back everything. If it does fail initally, the scheduled job will try at every N minutes, you can't ask for more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Is at least one of the servers Workgroup edition or higher? You can use Service Broker to ship your records instead of linked servers, but it will not work between to Express editions due to licensing restrictions. Is a solution relying exclusively on SQL, offers reliability in case of incidents (one of the servers is unavailable) and your updates will propagate in real time (as soon as they are committed). My site has many examples on how to do this, you can start with this article here on [how to achieve high message throughput](http://rusanu.com/2007/04/25/reusing-conversations/).

Comment: I could write workaround anywhere in the java app that uses this sql table but this is like for one customer only so I hoped I could isolate the entire thing in sql trigger and forget about it. Thanks for the Service Broker article.