# When trigger failed to write in remote server, write to local server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, insert

First sorry for my English.

I have one server when receives an update in specific table, I want write to a remote server too, but if the remote server is unavailable, I want the trigger to write to the local server in another temp table.

Example code to write to remote server:

```
-- REMOTO is remote server
CREATE TRIGGER insertin
ON mangas
AFTER INSERT 
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @serie varchar(max), @capitulo int 

    SELECT @serie = serie ,@capitulo = capitulo
    FROM inserted

    INSERT INTO [REMOTO].[Gest].[dbo].[MARCA] (Codigo, Descripcion)
    VALUES (@capitulo, @serie)
END
```

I need, for example, something like `TRY...CATCH` or similar. I don't know how can I do it.

Thanks for answers and sorry for my English again.

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926467/testing-linked-server-conccetion-inside-trigger-or-procedure and here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8693/why-try-catch-does-not-suppress-exception-in-trigger

Comment: It would be better to *only* write to a local table from the trigger, and then have something else (e.g. an SQL job, SQL broker, etc) perform the remote access. Remote connections can take a *long* time to fail, and that's time that's preventing the local transaction that ran the `INSERT` from actually committing. Also, your trigger is broken - `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *many* rows.

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can put a TRY...CATCH block round your INSERT statement. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175976(v=sql.90).aspx

```
BEGIN TRY

    INSERT INTO [REMOTO].[Gest].[dbo].[MARCA]
        (Codigo, Descripcion)
         VALUES
           (   @capitulo, @serie ) 

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTemporaryTable]
        (Codigo, Descripcion)
         VALUES
           (   @capitulo, @serie ) 
END CATCH
```

Comment: if I try do it, dont work, the trigger enter in catch but dont do second insert.

Answer (score 0):

i do with this code and works well.
if anyone has better solution , please post, I'm learning t-sql now.
any advice is well come

```
begin 


declare
@serie varchar(max),
@capitulo int,
@maxMarca int


select @serie = serie
from inserted
select @maxMarca =max(Codigo) from [REMOTO].[Gest].[dbo].[MARCA]      

set @maxMarca = @maxMarca+1
commit -- save transaction insert which generates this trigger work.
begin TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY   
        INSERT INTO [REMOTO].[Gest].[dbo].[MARCA]  (Codigo, Descripcion)   VALUES   ( @maxMarca, @serie)             
        commit transaction --save transaction and finish, if remote server work
    END TRY    
    BEGIN CATCH                

    IF @@trancount > 0
        begin           
        rollback transaction   --remote transaction is  go back
            INSERT INTO [mangas].[dbo].[mangasTemp]  VALUES  (@maxMarca, @serie)        
        commit transaction   -- save transaction in local temporal table.
        end
    END CATCH


   end

       go
```

Comment: This trigger is still broken in terms of the remote server since it's using it to obtain `@maxMarca`. This trigger is still broken in that `inserted` can contain 0, 1, or multiple rows. This trigger is *probably* broken by assuming that the value of `MAX(Codigo)` has remained unchanged between the `SELECT` and the `INSERT` and/or by parallelism.

Comment: No, it really doesn't. You haven't addressed any of the issues I raised in my previous comments.