# Have a trigger stored in database1 that triggers when a table in database2 is updated, both databases in a linked server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As the long title says:

I have the database of "my" software (lets call it Database2) and a 'local' work database of my team to work and create objects (Lets call it Database1), that is linked via linked server with the Database2.
I know how to write and make complex triggers, I've done some in the Database2.

What I want to know is, can I write a trigger and store it in the Database1 that will look and trigger when the update I want to monitor happens in a table in Database2?

The motive for this is that we can no longer create objects in the Database2, we can only create objects in Database1.

If its possible, could you show me what is necessary for me to put in it so it 'look' to another database?
Or at least show me some article or key works that I can research about?
I tried to look it on google but couldn't find anything about it.

Thanks

Comment: You can't write a trigger on another database. You can only monitor it, i.e. regularly query it to see if the data changes.

Comment: @DaleK Do you mean, something like store the status of what I want to monitor in a table, than every day look if anything changed. Comparing the monitored table with the 'photograph' i 'take' from it every day?

Comment: Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

1. **If both databases `Database1` and `Database2` are in same server:** you can do something like INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger on `Database2`, which takes care of updating both `Database1` and `Database2`.[Refer to MSSQLTips for cross database linked server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5919/sql-server-referential-integrity-across-databases-using-triggers/)
2. **If both databases `Database1` and `Database2`are in different servers:** don't use linked server to UPDATE another table inside trigger. Create a job in server of `Database2`, which polls for the changes in the `Database2` and inserts into `Database1`. [Refer to SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926467/testing-linked-server-conccetion-inside-trigger-or-procedure#926537)

**Update**:

3. **If you are not able to create objects in `Database2`**: you can create job in `Database1` server, which polls for the changes in the `Database2` table using linked server, every N minutes (depending on your latency SLA) and then propagate those changes to `Database1`. It is similar to Option 2, but the job residing on `Database1` server side, which is polling for changes.

Comment: But OP says specifically **The motive for this is that we can no longer create objects in the Database2**

Comment: @DaleK, understood. I have updated my answer.